# getting index.php 404 file not found for a specific folder using nginx server + php

Tags: php, nginx, server, http-status-code-404

Trying to give access to index.php in a folder (which is not under *root*). Nginx seem to not be able to find the *index.php* file in *eaophp*, whereas *index.html* are found in both *eao* and *eao2*.

Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html/moodle;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  192.168.10.115;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /eao {
    alias /var/www/html/eao;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /eao2 {
    alias /var/www/html/eao2;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /eaophp {
    alias /var/www/html/eaophp;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /dataroot/ {
    internal;
    alias /var/www/html/moodledata/;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name 192.168.10.115;
    return 302 https://$server_name;
}
```

Comment: This might work , Add with fastcgi "fastcgi_index index.php;"

Comment: @Rahuljuneja-DevOps, I tried adding "fastcgi_index index.php;" into *location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$){* and got an error '"fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate'. When adding "fastcgi_index index.php;" in location eaophp, I still get the 404 not found error.